# How to use fixed div so its doesn't overlap with footer?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a HTML structure like this

[image]

Here i want div3 is fixed. But this is overlapping to footer on scroll like this

[image]
but i don't want to overlap my footer with fixed dive.

Can we do anything in css so it remains within continer?

here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b7cjb095/1/

```
.container{
  border: 1px solid; 
  float:left;
  width:75%;

}
.sidebar {
  border: 1px solid; 
  position:fixed;
  float:right;
  bottom:0;
  width:25%;
  right:0;

}

.footer{
  border: 1px solid;

}
.main {
   min-height: 600px;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: try the property overflow : hidden. or its better to give the fiddle with your code

Comment: post some code , what have you tried till now ?

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: I don't think this is possible with just CSS. If you're willing to use Bootstrap, they have functionality just like this called 'affix' where you can set top and bottom offsets for when elements should become fixed. If you're wanting to avoid frameworks you'd have to calculate when the bottom of your fixed div reaches the top of your footer and then set its position to `absolute`.

Answer (score 1):

i did it with jquery.You could use something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop()+$('#Div-3').position().top + $('#Div-3').height() > $('#Footer').position().top)
    //Here u can place code to lock the Div
    //Like Position:Absolute
    //bottom:0
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide me an answer now

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jameswassinger/2wwdoj3j/2/) that hopefully fixes your issue. I just adjusted some of the CSS classes and attributes to achieve the desired layout.

Let me know if that helps.

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body { margin-bottom: 60px;}

.main {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.container{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid; 
  width: 75%;
  
}
.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 8px;
  border: 1px solid; 
  float:right;
  top: 0;
  width:25%;
  right: 0;
}

.footer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px 5px 30px 5px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="container">
some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrensome conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent e conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrensome conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrensome conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some 
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some conrent some side bar side bar side bar side bar side bar side bar side bar side bar side bar side bar side bar side bar side bar side bar 

</div>

</div>

<div class="footer">

some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer some footer 
</div>
```